# RestKit JSON nested square Brackets

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, cocoa-touch, restkit

**For my JSON I want to get the following format:**

```
"fromTrigger":{
    "id":1,
    "fieldId":2,
    "type":"FROM"
}
```

**But with my mapping I get the following:**

```
"fromTrigger":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "fieldId":2,
        "type":"FROM"
    }
]
```

As you can see, I have the extra square braces "[ ]" in the second one.

**I have the following mapping:**

```
RKObjectMapping* fromTriggerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ActianTriggers  class]];
[fromTriggerMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"triggerId"];
[fromTriggerMapping mapKeyPath:@"fieldId" toAttribute:@"fieldId"];
[fromTriggerMapping mapKeyPath:@"type" toAttribute:@"type"];
[fromTriggerMapping mapKeyPath:@"filters" toRelationship:@"filters"     withMapping:triggerMapping serialize:YES];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:fromTriggerMapping   forKeyPath:@"fromTrigger"];
```

UPDATE:
Thank you for the quick responses, my question is that how can I have my JSON for the "FromTrigger" block to only have curly braces and not square braces also. From the two JSONs above I want to achieve the format of the first one. I require this because other wise the web service throws an error.

ActianTriggers Class (Following is the header file, the .m only synthesizes these variables):

```
@interface ActianTriggers : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *triggerID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *fieldId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray  *filters;
@end
```

Comment: What kind of thing is `ActianTriggers`?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of ActianTriggers, as well as the triggerMapping? It would also be helpful to see the snippet associated with the JSON generation. I'm assuming you're attempting a PUT/POST, but the exact code snippet would be helpful in determining what is going on with the serialization operation.

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance `fromTrigger` is a dictionary, in the second instance `fromTrigger` is an array or one item and that item is a dictionary.

Note that in JSON parlance a `dictionary` is an `object`.

What is `ActianTriggers`? The mapping introspects the object to determine the kind of mapping to make.

From the `RKObjectMapping`[documentation](http://restkit.org/api/0.9/Classes/RKObjectMapping.html) (the bold is mine):
1. keyPath to attribute. Defines that the value found at the keyPath should be transformed and assigned to the property specified by the attribute. The transformation to be performed is determined by **inspecting the type of the target property** at runtime.

See [Introducing JSON](http://www.json.org/).